# why the actionBar is placed at the bottom?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat, android-actionbaractivity

I was following some tutorials to learn how to create an activity with `ActionBar`, I followed the tutorial literally, but in the end, I found that the action bar is unlike the action bar resulted in the tutorial, mine is placed at the bottom of  activity and appears only when I press the `optionsMenueButton`, while the result from the tutorial is at the top. And my activity extends `ActionBarActivity` Any idea why that happens.

Java_Code:

```
public class ActionBarActivityTest00 extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_action_bar_activity_test00);


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.action_bar_activity_test00, menu);
    return true;
}
```

xml_file:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.actionbaractivitytest.ActionBarActivityTest00" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/search"
    android:title="Search"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_copy"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/copy"
    android:title="Copy"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_share"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/share"
    android:title="Share"/>
```

Comment: Can you post actual code? And perhaps a link to the tutorial you were following?

Comment: @Blackunknown please find the code posted, and unfortunately i lost tracking the tutorial's website

Comment: Shouldn't your return be "return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);" for starters?

Comment: @Blackunknown actually i,m not sure because this method is auto generated

Comment: If android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"  is specified in the manifest, part of the actionbar will show up on the bottom.  I'm not sure about why it would appear only when the menu button is pressed.  Try the emulator or another device to see if the behavior is consistent.